Why should this code be expecting a comma?
I am watching this course focused on programming for beginners. So, the instructor wrote the following code:
let numberOfLines = 1;

console.log(`Line #`, numberOfLines);

My question is, why do I get an error if I do not put the comma (,) before "numberOfLines"?
If I don't write it, it sends me a message about expecting it to be added.
I tried writing the code without a comma, just for curiosity, which resulted in an error. Please, can anyone explain why it happens?

"why do I get an error if I do not put the comma"... because it's syntactically invalid? Not really sure what else to say. Perhaps you should read up on calling functions

This question is either asking for opinions or really needs clarity. If you want to know why the language was designed this way, you won't get a canonical answer better than "because that's how C does it". Otherwise, why would you expect console.log(\Line #` numberOfLines)` to not cause an error?

console.log(`Line #`, numberOfLines);

This code calls the log function on the console object. It provides two arguments to that function. "Line #" is the first argument, and numberOfLines is the second argument.
And a , is how you separate arguments in a function invocation. You need a comma between all function arguments so that javascript knows where one argument ends, and the next one begins.
It just part of the grammar of the language. You get an error without the comma because the language specification says that one is required. It's as simple as that.

console.log() is a function. A function has a set list of parameters that it expects. If you remove the comma, JavaScript does not know what you are trying to do - It thinks you are trying to pass 2 values for one single argument.
With the comma, JavaScript knows you are wanting to pass the value before the comma as the first argument, and the value after the comma as the second argument.
This link may be useful: Read More about console.log()
Hope this helps!
